# Find a solution of the Laplace equation $-\Delta u=1$ with boundary condition $u=0$ on a spherical shell

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let

- $n\ge 2$
- $B_\varepsilon$ and $\overline{B}_\varepsilon$ be the open and closed ball around $0$ with radius $\varepsilon>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively
- $R>0$, $\rho\in (0,R)$ and $\Omega:=B_R\setminus\overline{B}_\rho$

I'm searching for a solution of $$\left\{\begin{matrix}-\Delta u&=&1&\text{on }\Omega\\u&=&0&\text{on }\partial\Omega\end{matrix}\right.\tag{1}$$

---

I know the solution of $(1)$ for $\rho=0$, i.e. $\Omega=B_R$. In that situation $$u(r)=\frac{R^2-r^2}{2n}$$ is a radial solution of $(1)$.

However, I'm unsure how I need to deal with the boundary condition and find a solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deal with the spherical shell, you are still in the radial case. Hence, in the radial situation your problem is equivalent to
$$
-u_{rr}-\frac{n-1}{r} u_r = 1, \\
u(\rho) = u(R) = 0,
$$
where $r = |x|$.

The general solution is the following (due to WolframAlpha):

1) If $n=2$, then
$$
u(r) = c_1 \ln r + c_2 - \frac{r^2}{4}.
$$
2) If $n \geq 3$, then
$$
u(r) = \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{c_1 n x^{2-n}}{2-n} - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) + c_2.
$$

Using now the boundary data $u(\rho) = u(R) = 0$ you can uniquely define $c_1$ and $c_2$.